# How can I get the frame of one of the x-axis labels in the horizontal bar chart of Charts?

Tags: swift, charts

I've created a bar chart by using the Charts framework. Currently, I'm trying to draw a red circle underneath the current day. However I'm not able to get a reference to the bounds nor the frame of the x-axis labels. How could I achieve this?

What I want to achieve is something like the added image

[image]

Comment: can u please make the question more clear. by adding chart image or something..

Comment: I added an image. I want to be able to get the frame of "do" and add a red circle underneath it.. Note this is an image I created with Excel